# How to create a std::array with std::transform without default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std, stdarray

I have a `std::array<Foo, 10>` and I would like to create a `std::array<Bar, 10>` using a function from `Foo` to `Bar`. Ordinarily I would use `std::transform` like so:

```
array<Bar, 10> bars;
transform(foos.begin(), foos.end(), bars.begin(), [](Foo foo){
    return Bar(foo.m_1, foo.m_2);
});
```

However, `Bar` doesn't have a default constructor, so I can't create the `bars` array. I could always use `vector` but it would be nice to be able to use `array` to guarantee that that I always have exactly 10 elements. Is that possible?

Comment: You could use something like a [not-quite-yet](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1njair/stdoptional_and_stddynarray_removed_from_c14_and/)-std [std::optional](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional) to wrap the Bar for the purposes of this array.  At least that would not force Bar to have a default constructor in general, and it's a useful include to have in a project anyway (imo).

Comment: Would a `vector.reserve(10)` not be sufficient in your code for the size `10`, or do you want to ensure client code doesn't change that size as well?

Comment: In this case `vector.reserve` works fine but it's not idea, as semantically this collection must have 10 items, and that won't work in all cases. Image if I have to pass it to a function that accepts a `std::array<Bar, 10>&`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not with `std::transform`, but nothing a little template magic can't fix.

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
std::array<Bar, N> foos_to_bars(const std::array<Foo, N>& foos,
                                std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return {{ Bar(foos[Is].m_1, foos[Is].m_2)... }};
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
std::array<Bar, N> foos_to_bars(const std::array<Foo, N>& foos) {
    return foos_to_bars(foos, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

[`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and friends are C++14, but easily implementable in C++11. There are probably half a dozen implementations on SO alone.

Comment: Why the double braces in the return statement of `foos_to_bars` ? Does it have to do with creating a pack expansion context ? If so is `{{ ... }}` better than the others you've showcased in SO (eg `expander`) ?

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou Nah, just silences some compiler's "missing braces" warning. (`std::array` is an aggregate containing a built-in array; the outer braces are for `std::array`; the inner for the built-in one. You are allowed to elide the inner braces, but some compiler warns if you do that.)